# NAS JBOD2 2 Drive Raid 0 Enclosure Failure Data Recovery

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I have a Caldigit Enclosure that had 2 2TB Sata Hard Drives in the unit. The Enclosure seems to have failed during a data recovery operation where the partition was lost during a power failure.

I am now at the point of trying to recover this data by other means, I was wondering if there was a way to mount these two drives on a ubuntu platform using the sata interface so I can either try to restore the partition or recover the data.
The information on the drive characteristics is below:

```
*-disk:0
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdg
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: sectorsize=512
  *-disk:1
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.1
       bus info: scsi@8:0.0.1
       logical name: /dev/sdh
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       configuration: sectorsize=512
root@bench:/home/trinsic# 
root@bench:/home/trinsic# mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sdh
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdh.
root@bench:/home/trinsic# mdadm --misc --examine /dev/sdg
/dev/sdg:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

Comment: What was the file system? You may need to reconstruct the Raid 0. I have in the past had pretty good success with [RAID Reconstructor](https://www.runtime.org/raid.htm)

Comment: I was kind of hoping for a linux alternative is this possible in linux?

Comment: Is there some reason why there isnt any further response on this? is there a way to do this in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RAID0 you need both drives to reassemble the RAID to recover data. If as you say the original partitioning is lost then you will need to fix the partitioning or find the offset that will let you access the mdadm metadata.

You might try Testdisk to see if it can find the partitioning info.

Also there is a free RAID recovery tool called ReclaiMe that will scan your drives for RAID config parameters.

And check if there is any output if you run the command... cat /proc/mdstat

Comment: Thanks for your response, I ran testdisk and UFS explorer with the two drives in a new raid enclosure of the exact same model. It was not able to find the partition, just a bunch of HFS+ partitions that were out side the disks physical boundaries. Since I am unable to recover the partition, I have moved onto file recovery. The problem now is that the file recovery is showing more data on the drive that is physically possible. 50TB on a 4TB raid configuration, any ideas about that?

Comment: If it sees 50TB then there is obviously a problem. Adding the drives to a new RAID enclosure may be a mistake. You need to be looking at each raw drive. For any file recovery to work you need to assemble the RAID with the correct drive order and chunk size. That is why I suggest you try Reclaime.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but to be clear this is not a problem with the array. Its the identical raid enclosure to the old one. the file recover has found the files on the drive, I can read them and open them up with no problems. It just says that the size of the recovery of all the files on the array is 50tb for some reason, so I dont think its a problem with the array since the enclosure has the built an identical raid controller and the order of the drives are the same.

Comment: sorry  I meant to say I dont think its a problem with the array, but maybe you are right, I will try reclaime, im sorry this is getting really frustrating because when the drives are out of the enclosure and inside of a 2 drive usb3.0 enclosure, with the array assembled with the proper block size the scanning speed goes down significantly.

Comment: Ok I downloaded reclaime, it looks like it found the proper settings for the array. Thank you it looks like you were right. The problem is now, since the partition looks like its shot, based on scanning it in UFS explorer: Shows an unknown partition at 2047 when there is suppose to be a HFS+ partition at that location. Is there a way to do file recovery on this virtual raid now that the raid configuration looks different and correct? I saved the raid layout to a file. Is there a way to build a virtual array in linux? I have to image files for both drives and the xml file.

Comment: I believe with Reclaime you can write the array to an image file. Once you have the image created you can use Linux tools on it. Give Testdisk and Photorec a try.....Or build the RAID in R-Studio and let it do a scan.

Comment: I dont have enough space to write a 4tb image to, is there another way?

Comment: Also R-Studio does not support 1k block sizes so I can use that software. And UFS explorer does not do file recovery. Whats interesting is I downloaded the trial version of Reclaime Me which is a file recovery tool and it looks like its reading the the HFS+ file structure now. When I go into UFS explorer it says the partition type is unknown. is there a way to recreate the HFS plus partition?

Comment: As I recall R-Studio does support custom chunk sizes, just type it in. If you can find space to make an image it gives you a lot of flexibility to use a range of tools to recover from the image.

Comment: Ok I found a 4tb drive, im writing the the array to the disk and will see what r-studio does, thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I used Reclaime Free RAID Recovery to create to images of the disks and used Reclaime Data Recovery software to recover the entire filesystem structure and files. I tried Photorec, and R-Studio, both could not find the file structure. Appreciate your time for helping me on this

Comment: Thanks for the update...always good to hear about successful outcomes.